# Математические операции с матрицами?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Можно ли решать задачи по линейной алгебре с использованием только библиотеки Pandas и её DataFrame? Или для этого всё таки придётся переводить `df` в массивы NumPy и дальше работать с ними? И если да, то есть ли какой-нибудь туториал/манул по решению матричных примеров с использованием исключительно Pandas?

Я застопорился в простом примере, как из DataFrame вычленить вектор-столбец и сделать из него вектор-строку (транспонировать).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Туториалы:

- [Pandas для начинающих (`10 minutes to Pandas`)...](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html)
- [Рецепты](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/cookbook.html#cookbook)

Если очень грубо, то Pandas.DataFrame можно рассматривать как словарь, у которого имена столбцов - это ключи, а значениями являются Pandas.Series и значения индекса для всех столбцов / Series совпадают.

Примеры:

```
In [132]: df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3], "b": [20, 30, 40]})

In [133]: df
Out[133]:
   a   b
0  1  20
1  2  30
2  3  40

In [134]: df[["b"]].T
Out[134]:
    0   1   2
b  20  30  40

In [135]: df["b"].to_numpy()
Out[135]: array([20, 30, 40])
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Теперь застрял на вычислении обратной матрицы. Похоже всё-таки не обойтись без перевода в numpy для осуществление матричных вычислений.

Comment: @leach, я не вижу в этом особой проблемы... `df.to_numpy()` - вернет вам соответствующую Numpy матрицу